# How can I make the "back button" appear, for a subview?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic, and what causes me most difficulty is the subject of navigation.
I have two tabs called "Dashboard" and "friends". I would like that when I click on the dashboard button, I can navigate to the subview that is called "subview_dash", but I do not want the tabs to be shown in this view. My problem is that I know how to navigate to this view, but I can not make the return button appear in "subview_dash".

[image]
[image]

How can I do it? I would appreciate it too.

```
.state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.friends', {
    url: '/friends',
    views: {
      'tab-friends': {
        templateUrl: 'tab-friends.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('subview_dash', {
    url: '/subview_dash',
        templateUrl: 'tab-subview_dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'

  })
```

This is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Az3w9O8rkr7fJw4unIDz?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You use this code in tab-subview_dash.html

```
<ion-view title="subview_dash">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      <button class="button button-clear ion-arrow-left-c" ng-click="backButton()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
       friends
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and write your function for backButton() give path where you want to redirect